# Looking for a word or phrase for a difficult transition that involves building momentum

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm actually imagining the experience of children having to transition from their own activity to something their parents need them to do, but comparing that experience to something like a crew having to change the direction of a ship in short order. The main effort is starting the change; then the change is caught up in the momentum.

"Parents promise ice cream to help children------------" [so they can move on to the next thing on the agenda.]

Comment: There seem to be too many things going on here. Depending on verb or noun, you could use **motive**, **motivation**, or **incentive**. But I can't think of a set phrase that would mean "something their parents need to them to do," or something that would mean it in terms of building up momentum. (**Bootstrap**, **shoehorn**, **leverage**, **ease into**, or **transition into**?)  I would just go with a verb or noun and then construct your own phrase.

Comment: With children it can be matter of **diverting** them from one thing to another.

Comment: Redirect their momentum.

Comment: How about *impel*?

Comment: Given the "momentum" connection, I'm thinking about *overcoming inertia*.

Comment: _get going_ sounds good to me.

Answer (score 1):

How about the idiom **get into gear**? From M-W:

> **[get into gear](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/get%20in%20gear)**: to start working or doing something in a more energetic and effective way; to cause (something) to start working or becoming successful

Your example:

> *Parents promise ice cream to help children **get into gear** so they can move on to the next thing on the agenda.*

**Get into gear** suggests not only *motion* but *momentum*.

I also considered *[light a fire under someone](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/light-a-fire-under-someone)* but decided it was not only a poor fit but a dangerous way to get children to move more quickly. :-)

Answer (score 1):

"Parents promise ice cream to motivate their children."

Remarks: To do what the parents have asked. In the next sentence, you can describe what you hope that is. (Unless treats are repeated regularly, motivation will fade.)

Answer (score 1):

**Get the ball rolling**

Without rewriting too much, based on your phrase for incentivized motivation, "Parents can promise ice cream to [**get the ball rolling**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/start-set-get-the-ball-rolling) on the next task."  Get the ball rolling and it will keep going.

It sounds like carrot ice cream, which can lead to stickiness.